# python - how to implement 'send one request, wait for multiple responses' synchronization?

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization

I am writing some code to communicate with a MCU via a serial port.
The MCU side is basically a request/response server.
My application sends one request, the MCU sends back one or more responses.
However, the responses can arrive asynchronously and with random delay, but the order of responses will be kept.
Also, my application can send multiple requests at a time.

I create one thread for each request.
And only one common thread is used for receiving from the serial port.

Currently structure is like this:

The request thread writes to the serial port, adds its identity to the waiting list, and then wait for an Event.
The receiving thread receives a response, looks up in the waiting list, if a matching request thread is waiting, it removes the waiting list entry, and set the Event.
The request thread gets notified about the Event and continue processing.
This works well if only one response is received per request.

Now say two responses are expected.
After processing the first response, the request thread adds itself to the waiting list again, and wait for another Event.

Normally, the receiving thread when receives the second response and does the same thing to set Event.

However, sometimes, the 2nd response just arrives too quick, before the request thread waits for the 2nd Event.

The sample code is as follows.

Request thread:

```
send_a_request(req)
add_waitlist(req, self)
self.event = threading.Event()
if not self.event.wait(1):
  remove_waitlist(req, self)
  #time out processing
else:
  # process 1st response
  add_waitlist(req, self)
  self.event = threading.Event()
  if not self.event.wait(1):
    remove_waitlist(req, self)
    # timeout processing
  else:
    # process 2nd response
```

Receiving thread:

```
receive_a_reponse()
for (req, thread) in waitlist:
  if a match is found:
    remove_waitlist(req, thread)
    thread.event.set()
    break
```

Comment: Have you tried spawning new threads (with a sufficiently related ID) for each response?

Answer (score 0):

You should lock before adding to the queue, and before removing.

```
# lock object common to all threads
lock = threading.Lock()

with lock:
    send_a_request(req)
    add_waitlist(req, self)
    self.event = threading.Event()
if not self.event.wait(1):
    with lock:
        remove_waitlist(req, self)
        #time out processing
else:
    # process 1st response
    with lock:
        add_waitlist(req, self)
    self.event = threading.Event()
    if not self.event.wait(1):
        with lock:
            remove_waitlist(req, self)
        # timeout processing
    else:
        # process 2nd response



receive_a_reponse()
with lock:
    for (req, thread) in waitlist:
        if a match is found:
            remove_waitlist(req, thread)
            thread.event.set()
            break
```